# Validation in ASP.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation

I want only letters and the special symbols `/` and `-` in my textbox.

How should be the expression like to give in custom validator?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: 20 questions and 0 accepted. voted to close just for this.

Comment: Binu, please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq It is important that you accept some of the answers given by people in order to keep people motivated to answer your questions. You just press the checkmark next to the answer that answers your question best. You will get points for each answer you accept, and the answerer will also get some. People answer questions to gain points, just FYI.

Comment: @Shoban: While there is some validity in your comment, the fact is that with a rate that low people will be less inclined to answer anyway. Your vote to close is spurious as it is a valid, clear question. That said, there's probably a number of other questions asking almost the same thing on SO, so your vote to close should be for "Exact Duplicate" (such as 1572357 which would get Binu started)

Answer (score 5):

You should use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx).

The expression should be something like `^[a-zA-Z/\-]+$`

If the text cannot be empty, you need a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) aswell, as all the other validators are only called if the text is not empty.

Comment: I think you mean more like this `^[a-zA-Z/\-+]*$ `.

Comment: @Steven, you are right, the regex was a bit off. I have updated it.